# I am trying to change jpanels within a jpanel, each Jpanel is a different class

Tags: java, panels

When I run my program I log in and then it goes to the main menu, from the main menu it should then go to the store room when store button is pressed but nothing shows up.

Here is the code to change jpanels

```
  jPanel2.setVisible(false);
  remove(jPanel2); 
  controlPanel = new JPanel();
  ShopStock panel = new ShopStock(); 
  controlPanel.add(panel); 
  controlPanel.setVisible(true);
```

What I tried to do is make the current jpanel visibility set to false, then I removed it from the screen, I then added a new jpanel to the screen, added the new class to the panel and made it visible, but nothing appears when the store button is pressed.

Comment: Consider using [CardLayout](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html) instead.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the new panel to the container. I suppose you are extending a JFrame or JPanel because you have the remove(jPanel2);

```
jPanel2.setVisible(false);
remove(jPanel2); 
controlPanel = new JPanel();
ShopStock panel = new ShopStock(); 
controlPanel.add(panel); 
controlPanel.setVisible(true);
add(controlPane);
validate(); //Or revalidate(); if validate doesn't work.
```

Hope it helps, it would be a good idear to check the CardLayout as RealSkeptic told you.The CardLayout is designe to interchange different panels and will have a better behaviour.